# WidgetKit is not requesting a new timeline

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

My widget does not request a new timeline. I have tried .atEnd and .after, but they both don't seem to work. After it's been at its last entry, it just stops updating the widget.

```
func getTimeline(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<Entry>) -> ()) {
    heartRate().refreshHeartRateData()
    
    var entries: [SimpleEntry] = []

    let currentDate = Date()
    let endDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .second, value: 10, to: currentDate)!
    print(currentDate)
    print(endDate)
    
    let entry = SimpleEntry(date: currentDate, heartRate: BPM, count: countClass().getNewCount())
    entries.append(entry)
    
    let timeline = Timeline(entries: entries, policy: .atEnd)
    completion(timeline)
}
```

Comment: Did you look at the [Widget Code Along](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=yv6so7ie)? Widgets are metered I doubt Apple will allows updates every 10 seconds. Also since most of the HealthKit methods are asynchronous, I think it would be correct to assume that `refreshHeartRateData()` and `getNewCount()` are not working as you expect.

Comment: Actually, I have written a piece of code in another project to test, and I am able to update every second. I have no idea why it isn't working here.

Comment: Widgets are limited to a [budget of 40 to 70 updates per day](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/keeping-a-widget-up-to-date).

Comment: Widgets are budgeted on a real device, but are unbudgeted in the simulator for accelerated testing. This code will work on the simulator without a second thought, but will only update about every 15 minutes on the device until your budget runs out. Definitely watch the Code Along.

Comment: I did watch the Code Along, but don't recall anything about an update budget. I did however find it on the Apple Developer Documentation. Thanks for pointing it out anyway!